# Dynamic Tool Tips

Tags: php, tooltip

Can anyone point me in the right direction. I've been searching forever, but can't find out how I can add a tool tip to dynamically generated data. For example, I'm producing a list of mysql results showing film titles and want to have a tool tip that gives extra info like director, actors, etc. when hovering mouse over. Random lists of film titles are generated each time.

I know how to add tooltips to static data, but how can I add tooltips on the fly?

Any pointers or shoves in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Just do what you do for static data... What is it that you normally do for that?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Prototip 2](http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip2/) inside PHP where the tips are generated on the fly as the page is generated.

Basically I have this code that creates a bunch of tooltips for a bunch of different items from the database.  This code is part of the HTML for the whole page.  This happens to be inside a zend framework view script, but is universal.

```
<?php foreach($this->items as $item): ?>
<?php if ($item['statusText'] != ''): ?>

tips.push(
        new Tip('led_<?php echo $item['boxsn']; ?>', '<?php echo $item['statusText']; ?>', {
stem: 'leftMiddle',
hook: { target: 'rightMiddle', tip: 'leftMiddle' },
style: 'protoblue',
offset: { x: 5, y: 0 }
})
);
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($item['alarms'] != ''): ?>

    tips.push(
        new Tip('alarm_<?php echo $item['boxsn'] ?>',
                '<?php echo $item['alarms'] ?>', {
            stem: 'leftMiddle',
            hook: { target: 'rightMiddle', tip: 'leftMiddle' },
            style: 'protoblue',
            offset: { x: 5, y: 0 }
        })
    );
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

That leaves me with output similar to the following for every tooltip I created:

```
tips.push(
    new Tip('led_091133000039', 'Item has not functioned since 02/03/12 01:30 PM', {
        stem: 'leftMiddle',
        hook: { target: 'rightMiddle', tip: 'leftMiddle' },
        style: 'protoblue',
        offset: { x: 5, y: 0 }
    })
);
```

I even use Ajax to refresh the item status and use the following to clear all the tips from memory so the new ones from the Ajax will become active:

```
// prior to ajax update
Tips.hideAll(); // prototip function to hide visible tooltips

tips.each(function(t) {
    delete t;
});

delete tips;
tips = [];

// run ajax update
```

Each ID like `led_091133000039` is the ID of the image I want to have the tooltip show when hovered over.  That HTML is generated earlier in the page.  I have the Javascript that creates all the tips at the bottom of the HTML.

Hope that helps you.